# Generic T.Type for a parameter not even used and comma separated constraints

Tags: swift, generics, swift3

Three questions about this code:

```
func register<T: UICollectionViewCell where T: ReusableView, T: NibLoadableView>(_: T.Type) {
    let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: T.self)
    let nib = UINib(nibName: T.nibName, bundle: bundle)

    registerNib(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: T.defaultReuseIdentifier)
}
```

1. `(_: T.Type)`. The block of code in this `func` doesn't even use this parameter. So why is `T.Type` even necessary and what the heck does it do to add `.Type` to the generic?
2. This line `T: UICollectionViewCell where T: ReusableView, T: NibLoadableView`, does it mean that:

   (a) T is constrained to type UICollectionViewCell that conforms to the protocols ReusableView ***and*** NibLoadableView?

   (b) Or does it mean that it conforms to ReusableView ***or*** NibLoadableView?
3. The third question arises from the above example but its not directly related. I can appreciate a generic that is constrained to specific types; but when a generic is constrained to one type, I don't see the difference between that and just a normal type declaration for an input variable. See code below

What's the difference between this:

```
func register<T: UICollectionViewCell>(whatever: T) {
  // whatever
}
```

and this:

```
func register(whatever: UICollectionViewCell) {
  // whatever
}
```

Don't both of the above declarations claim that `register` only expects a type constrained to `UICollectionViewCell`? How or in what case do they differ?

---

(Context the example code was extracted from: https://gist.github.com/gonzalezreal/92507b53d2b1e267d49a)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It means that the parameter is a metatype. The parameter is given a type, (a metatype), rather than an instance of that type. Here's an example:

   ```
   func f<T>(_: T.Type) {
       print(T.self) //Prints "String"
   }

   f(String.self) // A metatype, not an instance of String
   ```
2. It means **and**.
3. On its own like that, there's not much of a difference. The first example is using generics, and the second example is using polymorphism. Here's an example in which they differ:

   ```
   protocol Repairable {
       var broken: Bool { get set}
   }

   class Vehicle: Repairable {
       var broken = true
   }

   class CheapRepairableTrinket: Repairable {
       var broken = true
   }

   func repair<T: Repairable>(_ object: T) -> T {
       var object = object
       object.broken = false

       // The return type *must* be the same as the type of the parameter
       return object
   }

   func scamRepair(_ object: Repairable) -> Repairable {
       // the parameter type and the return type can be any Repairable
       // type, but there's no enforced relationship between them
       return CheapRepairableTrinket()
   }

   // I gave them a car to fix, and they gave me back some other crap!
   print(type(of: scamRepair(Vehicle())))
   ```